# How to use import range to import content into one single cell instead of entire row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using: = `ImportRange("<key>","B2:B")`

How I get it is:

[image]

But how I want it to be is:

[image]

into a single cell. Can anyone guide me to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `JOIN` and/or `TEXTJOIN`?

#### Modified formula:

```
=JOIN(",",ImportRange("<key>","B2:B"))
```

or

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ImportRange("<key>","B2:B"))
```

- By above modification, the retrieved values are put in one cell with the delimiter of `,`.

#### References:

- [JOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077)
- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)